# Linux does not send arp reply

Tags: linux, networking, arp

I have an interface keeping receiving arp request but never respond. Can anyone help?

My interface ip is 192.168.40.2.
[image]

[image]

The routing table looks good.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps similar to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205708/linux-does-not-reply-to-arp-request-messages-if-requested-ip-address-is-associat. Or perhaps [arp_ignore](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/ip-sysctl.html) is set.

Comment: @JoeLu Please use RAW text instead of images.